# How to fix navbar first item text is smaller/out of alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I used the outline of the code from we3schools. My problem is that the first item on the navbar ends up smaller and not level to the rest of the items.

Even when I remove the dropdown “books” the first item is always slightly lower than the rest and I have no clue how to fix this error.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28oAb.png)

I couldn't get the code to align where it would let me publish so here is the github link (it's an html file with just the navbar and a css file with just the navbar portion in it).

LINK: https://github.com/Terrancesky/website/tree/main

Comment: I don't think the navbar is smaller, just the alignment. Did you try inspecting and cross verifying with the code?

Comment: I've downloaded and opened your Index.html in both Firefox and Chrome. I can't see anything like the issue in your screenshot (kept zooming in until the mobile menu showed up, just in case my eyes were playing tricks). Can you try hard reloading the page, and checking if the issue persists?

Answer (score 0):

The code seem to be working fine when i copied it onto my [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/infinity01012003/pen/dyjjNPK?editors=1100)
there is no disalignment and a slight improvement you can made is to use the following code for your dropdown

```
<select>
<option> item 1</option>
<option> item 2 </option>
</select>
```